# RecyclerView click on position 0 also set as clicked of position 11

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, adapter

I am using `RecyclerView` in `Fragment`. clicking on `RecyclerView` items is also reflect on another position like, if i select 0 position position 11th also set as selected, if i select 1st position then position 12th also set as selected.

[image]

Here is my adapter class..

```
 List<Data> dataList;
Context context;
public static OnItemClick click;

public void setClick(final OnItemClick click){
    Wkdapter.click =click;
}
```

Here is BindView method

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Wkdapter.Holder holder, int position) {
    Data data=dataList.get(position);
    holder.tv_playername_create_team.setText(data.getName());

}

public static class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView tv_playername_create_team;
    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_playername_create_team=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_playername_create_team);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (click!=null){
                    int pos=getAdapterPosition();
                    if (RecyclerView.NO_POSITION!=pos){ ;
                        click.onClicked(itemView,pos);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here i set Onclick in fragment

```
  Wkdapter.setClick(new OnItemClick() {
                @Override
                public void onClicked(View view,int position){
                    data=dataList.get(position);
                    result.onResult(data,view,position);
                }
            });
```

onResult Method

```
@Override
public void onResult(Data data, View view, int position){
   Log.e(tag,"Name "+data.getName());

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for  result.onResult(data,view,position);?

Comment: Please also share your onBindViewHolder method

Comment: @ Levi Albuquerque  i also shared onResult method now

Comment: @Amrat Singh onBindViewHolder  is also shared now

Comment: @Ganger see the answer

Comment: are you sure when you clicking on position 0 the position 11 gets clicked? i mean not only in the view but is your  call Back  called again for position 11 when you click on the position 0 ?

Comment: @Amir Hossein Mirzaei I am not sure callback call again but yes, I am sure if I click on position 0 then 11 is get selected an on  1 position 12,on 2 position 13.

Comment: @AmratSingh really thanks for your response. I will use it in my code. In case I face any problem then let you know. Hope you help me again. :)

Comment: @Ganger i think it is because you are not setting your viewHolder.itemview to default state of you want and in your position 11 recyclerBiew is recycling your position 1 view and re uses the position 1 view in your position 11 but your are no setting view's property to default one in your on bindView you should check your data in onBindeView holder and look to your items and see if the position relevant item is select or not if it wasn't selected you should set your itemView to look like not selected view and if it was selected you should set the itemView to look like selected view !

Comment: @Ganger tell me if my comment worked for you !

Answer (score 1):

Similar to my experience, here's how I solve it:

1. Set onClick on the `onBindViewHolder()`. Make sure your `onClick` has the `position` from `onBindViewHolder()` parameters. Not from `getAdapterPosition()`.
2. In your `RecyclerView.Adapter`, override `getItemId(int position)` and `getItemViewType(int position)` return the `position`. Don't do anything else there.

In my case, it works.

Comment: Have you tried to move the holder.onClick to the `onBindViewHolder()` by passing the position given by the `onBindViewHolder()`, not from the `getAdapterPosition()`.

Comment: yes i applied like holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   click.onClicked(view,position);
                }
            });

Comment: Try to override `getItemViewType(position)` and return the position as well. See if that also works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with a recycled ViewHolder. Set the button to the proper state in the onBindViewHolder function. E.g. if the clicked state is stored in your Data object:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Wkdapter.Holder holder, int position) {
    Data data=dataList.get(position);
    holder.tv_playername_create_team.setText(data.getName());
    click.onClicked(data.isClicked)
}
```

Comment: do you mean i should use onClick method in onBindViewHolder ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to maintain selected position state in your Data class, create a boolean isSelected variable in Data class if you are not maintaining state and then also update it in onBindViewHolder if it is selected or unselected.

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Wkdapter.Holder holder, int position) 
 {
     Data data=dataList.get(position);

     if(data.isSelected()) {
//   Set icon of selected state
     } else {
//   Set icon of unselected state
     }

     holder.tv_playername_create_team.setText(data.getName());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code.

```
`@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Wkdapter.Holder holder, int 
 position){
    Data data=dataList.get(position);
    holder.tv_playername_create_team.setText(data.getName());
    if(data.isModified()){
       holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
    }else{
       holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
}`
```

change set click to this

`adapter.setClick(new OnItemClick() {
                @Override
                public void onClicked(View view ,int position){
                    data=dataList.get(position);
                    data.setModified(true);
                }
      });`

```
`@Override
 public void onResult(Data data, View view, int position){
    Log.e(tag,"Name "+data.getName());
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
  }`
```

Add one more field to Data class:

```
`class Data{
      boolean isModified;
      // other variables here
 }`
```

Comment: this works.. but actually as shown in shared Gif image, when i click on item the plus button rotate and change color of button..after implementing your code button is rotating during scrolling of recycler view..

Comment: Looks like you are animating the view on onBindViewHolder() . Check this link  http://frogermcs.github.io/instamaterial-recyclerview-animations-done-right/. This is the right way to do animations in the recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

Set `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);` in onBindViewHolder.